# HttpWebRequest with p12 cert + password

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest

I need to be authentificated with p12 cert (with password) + cookie.

Here is my code :

```
X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2();
byte[] rawCertificateData = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\mycert.p12");
certificate.Import(rawCertificateData, "c3rtifPassw0rd", X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://apidomain.com/getDatas");
request.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);
request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
request.CookieContainer.Add(new Cookie("apicookie", "myCookieString") { Domain = "apidomain.com" });
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), ASCIIEncoding.ASCII))
{
    result = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
return result;
```

The server returns a 400 error.

Comment: Do I do things well? (The server returns a 400 error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I don't have enough reputation to answer through a comment)
Based on my experience using webrequest, some servers reject non-standard requests; I mean, first, you need to be sure that you set all headers properly for the http request (user-agent, referer, language, etc.).

Then, ensure that you use .NET framework 4.5 or higher, since older versions have problems managing some certificates.

Comment: I'm using .NET Framework 4.6.1 - I've tryied to add the same headers I'm sending with google chrome, I still have the 400 error.

Comment: Play with the headers a little bit: redirections, protocol versions, etc. Don't trust default settings for request. As I said try to fill in as much data as possible.